# java.lang.NullPointerException when using adb to deploy apk to Android N phone

Tags: java, android, adb

I have an AndroidStudio project, which was originally able to deploy to my phone via adb.

But after I updated the phone to Android N, I could no longer use adb to deploy it.

```
$ adb install app-release.apk 
Failed to install app-release.apk: 
Exception occurred while dumping:
java.lang.NullPointerException: rhs == null
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Native Method)
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:1082)
    at java.util.Collections.indexedBinarySearch(Collections.java:299)
    at java.util.Collections.binarySearch(Collections.java:286)
    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isInApp2sdBlacklist(Settings.java:5622)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isInApp2sdBlacklist(PackageManagerService.java:21454)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.isInApp2sdBlacklist(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2534)
    at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:416)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:647)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:566)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1141)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerS
```

What could be the problem?

I have googled the error messsage and had no clue. Also, how to read this error message? It seems like the error is inside Android library or inside java library. (Is it because I updated java to a higher version?)

Comment: try restarting adb

Comment: @AmodGokhale Tried. Error message's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If you encounter the same problem

You could try following procedures, then maybe you'll figure out what your own problem is.

1. Generate an `.apk` file. (Use your AndroidStudio or whatever.)
2. `cd the\folder\containing\apk`
3. `adb push  name_of_the.apk  path\on\the\mobile\phone\storage\`
4. Manipulate the phone and manually install the `.apk` by clicking on the `.apk` file icon.

## The answer to my problem

Although `adb install` failed on my devices (as the problem statement describes), `adb push`(step 3 above) worked.

And after I did the step 4 above, an unexpected screen emerged.

[image: The system is scanning malicious software.]

It says, 'The system is scanning malicious software.'

So that's the answer to my problem. After I upgraded my phone to Android N version, the system has been added an automated software scanning, which will be triggered even if you're using developer mode and using adb.

And the error message didn't show anything of the clue. The error message just says `java.lang.NullPointerException: rhs == null` which is in no way related.

## Methods I tried but didn't work

1. Disable `instant run` in AndroidStudio.

   > `Settings`>`Build, Execution, Deployment` >`Instant Run`
2. `adb root`, `adb disable-verity`, `adb reboot`, `adb root`, `adb remount`

   > https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162902/adb-push-not-working-on-system-read-only